# Error redirected you too many times upon trying to install Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, redirect, htaccess

I just downloaded latest version of Magento 2.4 and I am trying to install it on Namecheap hosting but upon entering the URL of my website in the browser to start the setup wizard, it keep re-loading.

Before it immediately showed me error of "redirected you too many times", but now it just keep re-loading.
I contacted Namecheap support and they said that the issue is from htaccess file that causing redirecting issue. I also tracked the log in chrome network and I noticed that it keeps looping.

[image]

All files are raw and I did not change anything.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Setup by command. The setup widget removed.

Comment: Here is the command: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html#install-magento

Answer (score 0):

Install Magento with this command:

```
bin/magento setup:install
```

Or use next for help:

```
bin/magento help setup:install
```